# Convert date from xlsx dataset from YYYY.TEXT (e.g. 2012.916667) to a normal date format (e.g. 01/01/2012)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I've read in a xlsx file using pandas.read_excel and the dates on the dataset have come in like 2012.916667 for example. I can't figure out what the actual dates are as I don't have them so I'm not sure what the numbers mean. Anyone know how to convert them to normal dates? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, probably the owner of dataset wold be the best source for the answer.

Comment: That is a standard Excel date where the integer part is the number of days since the epoch and the decimal part is the percentage of the day. See for example: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html

Comment: The value shown in the question seems unusual to me. It could be a date. However, if this isn't on macOS it would represent some time in 5AD. On macOS it would be 4 years later

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it in the regular pandas Timestamp data format like so

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(2012.916667, unit='d', origin='1970-01-01')
```

[image]

```
# if the dates are loaded in a column, say, dates
pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], unit='d', origin='1970-01-01')
```

where the assumption is that the integer part is the number of days since the epoch (origin), and the decimal part is the percentage of day.

Since the data is coming from an excel file, the above assumptions are probably correct. Still, you should first get it confirmed from the data owner and use the appropriate parameters in the pandas function.